How to use labels in an image classification model in google colab
I'm trying to make a model that allows me to classify images of wifi and bluetooth spectrograms. this is the code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]

train_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/My training dataset/dataset + annotation'
valid_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/My training dataset/dataset with axis'

inception = InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in inception.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/My training dataset/dataset + annotation/*')

x = Flatten()(inception.output)

prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=inception.input, outputs=prediction)

#model.summary()

model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Use the Image Data Generator to import the images from the dataset
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/My training dataset/dataset + annotation',
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 16,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/My training dataset/dataset with axis',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 16,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

r = model.fit(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=len(training_set), validation_steps=len(test_set))

# train the model
r = model.fit(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=10,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)

# loss
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='train loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss')

# accuracy
plt.plot(r.history['accuracy'], label='train acc')
plt.plot(r.history['val_accuracy'], label='val acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('AccVal_acc')

from google.colab import files
from IPython.display import Image
uploaded = files.upload()

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

Upload the image and preprocess it

img_path = '/content/aez.png'
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
img_array = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0) / 255

Make the prediction

prediction = model.predict(img_array)

**Get the class with the highest probability**

predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)

print('Predicted class:', predicted_class)

The model is currently functional but it prints "class 0" for bluetooth and "class 1" for wifi.
I want to change the output text but I can't figure out how to do that.
I also manually labeled all images in my dataset with LabelImg and saved the annotations as a .txt file (I was asked to use txt format by my professor). and I don't know how to use it to re-train the  model.

Sorry, but I don't understand what the problem is. Is the model performing as expected? Do you want to print the class label as text? You mean with an if/else? i.e, if class == 0 label = "Bluetooth"... ? What about a dictionary?

That's one way of doing it thanks , but my problem is how do I use the annotations. When an image contains multiple signals the model outputs a random result. I'd like to know if there's a way that tells if both signals exist in an image it says that, and if only one of them exists it says only that signal is detected in the image.
